# Admin modules not loading when transferred to new server

Tags: adminhtml

Just transferred files from old server to new. When I go to access any modules in the menu they don't seem to work. I've refreshed cache, deleted sessions, checked config.xml for any anomalies and nothing pops out. Is there something else I should be looking for?

[image: Error on Admin]

Answer (score 2):

> Errors in system.log Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/htdocs/var/session/sess_3gik5vasun8ac8hevs16f7g581, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Says: Please give rights to write in `var/`

[You should reset the permissions for all the files](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions)

> Here’s how to reset your file and directory permissions if PHP is running through FastCGI, suPHP, or LSAPI:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 pear
chmod 550 mage #for magento 1.5+
```

> If PHP is running as a module (DSO), you will need to do this:

```
#for magento 1.5+
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
chmod 550 mage
chmod -R o+w media
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling each of the modules in question via there /app/etc/modules/MODULENAME.xml files?
So if you set them to false in the XML, then log out, log back into admin & refresh your cache.
Then go back, set them to true in the XML files, log out & log in again.

Are all the other admin menus working properly?
Do you get anything in your exception or system logs that looks suspect?

Comment: Just tried what you suggested and still getting the same issue.

Only the 3rd party extensions aren't loading.


Errors in system.log 

Warning: session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: open(/htdocs/var/session/sess_3gik5vasun8ac8hevs16f7g581, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)  in htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 123

User Notice: Sorry, your PCRE extension does not support UTF8 which is needed for the I18N core  in /lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 769

Comment: Congratulation, you found your error.